# Writing parallel TCP server in erlang

Tags: sockets, tcp, erlang

"Programming Erlang Software for a Concurrent World" says to write a parallel TCP server do like this:

```
start_parallel_server() ->
    {ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(...),
    spawn(fun() -> par_connect(Listen) end).

par_connect(Listen) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
    spawn(fun() -> par_connect(Listen) end),
    loop(Socket).

loop(...) -> %% handle request here
```

When `start_parallel_server` finishes its work it will close listen socket. Shouldn't we add something like `timer:sleep(infinity)` at the end of it?

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil gen_tcp will link to the process that call `gen_tcp:listen`. When this process goes down after `spawn(fun() -> par_connect(Listen) end).` then the listen socket will be closed too. I think we should add `timer:sleep(infinity)` at the end of `start_parallel_server()` so it doesn't finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `start_parallel_server()` from the shell the shell process will own the listening socket, so it will stay alive as long as that shell process is alive. Note that the shell process dies on exceptions and a new shell process is respawned… Can cause confusion.

But if you e.g. spawn a new process that in turn calls the `start_parallel_server()` function you will need a sleep in that spawned process to keep it alive.

Comment: Yes, it is the process which calls `gen_tcp:listen` which owns the socket and if it dies the listen socket, and all sockets which have been opened with it, will be closed. You can either call it from within a special process, or hand it over another process with `gen_tcp:controlling_process/2`.

Answer (score 3):

Moreover, for real world applications https://github.com/extend/ranch is more suitable.